# Can I have Sublime Text automatically run another command after Sublime SFTP plugin does upload?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Can I have Sublime Text automatically run another command after Sublime SFTP plugin performs an upload?  Maybe it could trigger a terminal command or system service (that I set up using OSX's Automator)?

This is what I am specifically trying to do...  I have Sublime SFTP configured to automatically upload on save.  I also have a system service which reloads the active tab in Safari.  I would love if pressing CMD-S to save, not only uploads, but reloads active browser tab after upload is complete.  Is there is a way I can trigger a command after the SFTP plugin is finished uploading?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options here:

1. There are plugins that support live-preview or refresh on save capabilities. For Example 
   https://sublime.wbond.net/search/Refresh or [LiveReload](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LiveReload)
2. The [Chain of Command](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) plugin allows you to execute multiple commands subsequently

Comment: I tried LiveReload, and it works... though if I have to wait for an upload, I have to set a delay so that browser refreshes after upload.  I am messing around with Chain of Command... thanks for recommendation.  I think this is the way to go :)  Do you know if Chain of Command supports command args though?

Comment: If you look at the readme for the "Browser Refresh" package, when setting key binding you can pass "activate_browser": true/false as argument into "browser_refresh" command.  My biggest problem with this workflow now is that when I use Chain of Commmand and Browser Refresh together, it sets focus on my browser by default.  If I could pass that "activate_browser":false argument into Chain of Command, I'd be really happy :)

Comment: @JerseyMilker Have you tried setting `"activate_browser": false` as default in your user-settings?